# .trn vs .bak backups of a database, both needed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I've just started working at a company where the guy who left told me they use transaction backup (I'm quite new to SQL Server, never heard of this before) and full backup for the 6 servers they have.

The servers use replication, one is a publisher and all others are suscribers.

In every server are jobs that run at night that create a .bak file (11GB) and around 25 .trn each night.

Are these .trn really necessary? The guy told me that if the trn backups are not done the server starts failing because "it fills" which I don't know what it means now that I think about it.

Do we really need a backup on every server? or should we only backup in the publisher?

Also, during the backup process the replication starts failing and I have to manually hit the "Restart" option every morning.

Comment: you will need to ask this question dba.se

Comment: they can give you pointers to start incase you are not aware where to start

Comment: edit the question too and ask for pointers ,so as not to get downvoted just in case